# Is there a way to show crosstab count of 0 in a plot.bar chart (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I'm fairly new to data analysis with Python. I was doing crosstab with my survey data just to count how many answers each answer got (1-5 rating) and then turned them into a plot.bar charts to visualize. I added colors from red to green to reflect the data better.

1 = red, 2 = orange, 3 = yellow, 4 = light green, 5 = green

Everything was fine until in one crosstab no one answered number 1 so in the plot.bar chart it only showed answers between 2-5 and also colored them incorrectly since there's only 4 answers now.
I tried dropna=False in the crosstab but it didn't do nothing.

Everything i have imported in the beginning (Don't know if this matters)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

%matplotlib inline

plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
```

The code showing how it's suppose to look and below, what went wrong
[image]

Is there a way to make the crosstab and/or plot.bar show all five categories of answers even if no one answered number 1 and start the colors from number 2 with orange?

Comment: Judging by the axis labels being converted to floats (2.0 instead of 2), I"m guessing you didn't actually drop the first record, but it has a null value.  Perhaps you can add `.fillna(0)` to the end of your crosstab.

Comment: I any case, it would be a good idea for your to post a sample of the df data, so we could copy it and try it on our end to help.  Always share sample data if you can.

Comment: `pd.crosstab` has a `dropna` argument that is set to `True` by default. You can try setting it to `False`...

Answer (score 0):

While you trying to use crosstab, don't know if it is a requirement. Below is an option of just grouping the data and plotting the same which will do what you need. Hope this solution is acceptable. You can first `groupby()` and count the number of occurrence of each value (1,2,3..). If any of the numbers 1-5 is not present, add a new row with 0. Post that, you can plot as you did in your code.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':[2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]})
rating=[1,2,3,4,5]
df_temp = df.groupby('col').agg({'col':'count'}).rename(columns={'col':'counts'}).reset_index() ## New dataframe with counts of 1,2,3
df_temp = df_temp.append(pd.DataFrame({'col' : [x for x in rating if x not in df['col'].unique()]})).fillna(0).astype(int).sort_values(by='col').reset_index() ##If any rating not present, add row with 0 count
df_temp['counts'].plot.bar(color = ('#EE9494', '#EEB594', '#EEDD94', '#CFEE94', '#9FEE94'))
```

[image]